# Remote Power Reset (RPM) on EVM doesnt work

Tags: code-composer

We have CI set up and very often our EVM boards (DSP boards) goes into a wrong state (reason unknown!!)and USB emulation was failing; to over come the issue we used to power reset the EVM board and everything used to work fine;

Now we have started using RPM (Remote Power Management) utility using which we can remotely reset the power on the device but unfortunately this doesnt seems to be working fine!!

We are able to reset the power on the EVM Board but we are unable to bring back the EVM board to working condition we are still getting USB emulation failure!!

Any thoughts on this; BTW we tried mulitple times resetting the power on EVM board using RPM but still same issue

Appreciate your help in this regard.

Raju

Comment: Hard to say...  Think about what's different between a manual powercycle (which you claim works, but does it still do? Tested that?) and the automatic powercycle generated by the RPM.  Maybe a difference in the length of the off-part of the powercycle?  But as you are not giving any specifics whatsoever that's just guessing.

Comment: @fvu: here answers to your questions
*. Think about what's different between a manual powercycle (which you claim works, but does it still do? Tested that?) and the automatic powercycle generated by the RPM*




ANS: in manual step we just remove the power connection from EVM board and connect it back and in automated way (RPM) we restart the EVM board using RPM;



May be you are right the length of the powersupply might be one of the issue!! will further check; unfortunately RPM is very new to us as well and we are trying to explore :(